# Assertion failure when reading from a map

Tags: c++, vector, assertion

```
int main(){


//Date Variables
int day;
int month;
int year;

string comName;
string temp;
string temp2;

//Time Variables
int hours;
int minutes;
int seconds;
string amPm;


ofstream ofstr("output.csv");

float price = 0.00;
int volume;
float value = 0.00;

float runningVol = 0.00;
float runningVal = 0.00;


float runningPrice = 0.00;

string condition;

string fileName;
string tempCName;

string compDate;


ifstream inFile;
ifstream compFile;
ifstream mainFile;

map<string, Vector <Share>> stlMap;

inFile.open("code_index.txt");

if(inFile.is_open()){
    while(!inFile.eof()){
        getline(inFile,tempCName);
        cout << "read next line in code_index" << endl; 

         comName = tempCName+"\\sales_index.txt";

         cout << "Company name to open is: " << comName << endl;

         compFile.open(comName);

         if(compFile.is_open()){
             while(!compFile.eof()){
                getline(compFile,fileName);
                cout << "Read the fileName: " << fileName << endl;

                fileName = tempCName+"\\"+fileName;

                mainFile.open(fileName);
                if(mainFile.is_open()){

                Vector <Share> myVec;

                    while(!mainFile.eof()){
                        compDate = "";
                        cout << "Stored all the variables" << endl;
                        //Getting and storing the Date
                        getline(mainFile,temp2,'/');
                        day = atoi(temp2.c_str());


                        getline(mainFile,temp2,'/');
                        month = atoi(temp2.c_str());

                        getline(mainFile,temp2,' ');                                    
                        year = atoi(temp2.c_str());

                        //cout << "date = " << day << "mo = " << month << "yr = " << year;

                        //Date d;
                        Date d(day,month,year); //Sending them to the Date class using the parameterized constructor

                        compDate = tempCName + "_" + d.returnDate();
                        //cout  << "Date is: "<< compDate << endl;

                        cout << compDate << endl;

                        // Getting and storing the time variable
                        getline(mainFile,temp2,':');
                        hours = atoi(temp2.c_str());

                        getline(mainFile,temp2,':');
                        minutes = atoi(temp2.c_str());

                        getline(mainFile,temp2, ' ');
                        seconds = atoi(temp2.c_str());

                        getline(mainFile,temp2,',');
                        amPm = temp2;

                        //Time t;
                        Time t(hours,minutes,seconds,amPm);
                        //cout << "Hours = " << hours << "minutes = " << minutes << "seconds = " << seconds << " " << amPm;


                        getline(mainFile,temp2,',');
                        price = atof(temp2.c_str());
                        //cout << price;

                        getline(mainFile,temp2,',');
                        volume = atoi(temp2.c_str());

                        getline(mainFile,temp2,',');
                        value = atof(temp2.c_str());

                        getline(mainFile,temp2,'\n');
                        condition = temp2;

                        Share s(price,volume,value,d,t);

                        myVec.push_back(s);


                    }
                    stlMap[compDate] = myVec;
                    mainFile.close();
                }
                else{ cout << "Specified day file not found";}
             }       
         compFile.close();
         }

         else{cout << "Specified company folder not found / sales_indexfile not found" << endl;}
    }
    inFile.close();
}
else

{cout << "code_index.txt not found. Please make sure the file exists";}

for(map<string, Vector <Share>>::iterator itr = stlMap.begin();itr!=stlMap.end() ;itr++ )
{
            cout << "map values\n";
            //cout << itr->first << endl;
            //cout << itr->second.length() << endl;
}

int iii = 0;
cin >> iii;

return 0;
```

}
I have my own templated vector, but this for loop to print from the map causes an assertion error, help please?

Also, if I comment out the bit where I enter into the map, the error is gone.
which makes me say, the vector isnt the cause of the issue.

Comment: complete code "http://pastebin.com/HHFHzTxU"

Comment: I bet it isn't map, but it is this `Vector` class that is the cause of issue.

Comment: also, it does cout the map contents, exits the for loop, and then i try to read in a int i; youknow, just so the program doesnt close. then causes an assertion error

Comment: and I've actually tested the vector before sending it to the map,

initially all the data went to the vector, there was no map, i just cout the length of the vector, that worked. only when i integrated the map, this error occured

Comment: You should post your code here, not at a link that some can't get to, and in addition, that link will probably be gone in the future, thus making the question worthless.

Comment: *and I've actually tested the vector before sending it to the map*  -- You tested whether the `Vector` class has correct copy semantics?  That is what is needed if you plan to store it as a data item in a map.  In other words, if it contains pointers to dynamically allocated memory, and it does not have a user-defined copy constructor, assignment op, and destructor, then it will cause all sorts of problems when placed in a map.  For a test. replace your home-made `Vector` with `std::vector`.  Do you still see an issue if you did that?

Comment: No, post `Vector` as it still is not clear what it is, what it has, what it does, how it works, whether it is copyable, etc.  And what is `Share`?

Comment: I conclude my vector was poorly created, and that using a std vector solved it. your bet came true. well actually for our university assignment 1, we had to create our own vector, and not encapsulate it in a std vector or something. So since the assignment was a success, I assumed my vector is perfect. In this assignment we are allowed to use the std vector (luckily), and using the std vector solved my problem. thanks @paulMcKenzie

Comment: More than likely, your `Vector` class wouldn't pass the [copy \ test program](http://ideone.com/F5yRjy).  Run your `Vector` through that code -- it should not cause any memory leak, double deletion errors, etc.  Those operations you see in `main` is similar to what `std::map` will be performing on your class.

Comment: I got a runtime error, it seems my copy constructor isnt copying properly hence the error, thanks a lot @PaulMcKenzie